# error when synchronizing CONTEXT index

Tags: database, oracle, admin, sql-grant, full-text-indexing

I  have a full text database application with a simple procedure which inserts values into a table:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE put_file
 (
  p_file_name         IN my_doc.file_name%TYPE,
  p_upload_date       IN my_doc.upload_date%TYPE,
  p_filesize          IN my_doc.filesize%TYPE,
  p_filetype          IN my_doc.filetype%TYPE,
  p_creation_date     IN my_doc.creation_date%TYPE, 
  p_modification_date IN my_doc.modification_date%TYPE, 
  p_accessed_date     IN my_doc.accessed_date%TYPE
) AS
 dummy pls_integer;
 BEGIN

  select count(*) into dummy from my_doc where file_name = p_file_name;

  if dummy = 0
      then
         INSERT INTO my_doc (id, file_name, upload_date, filesize, filetype, content, creation_date, modification_date, accessed_date)
         VALUES (my_doc_seq.NEXTVAL, p_file_name, p_upload_date, p_filesize, p_filetype, BFILENAME('DOCUMENTS',p_file_name), p_creation_date, p_modification_date, p_accessed_date);

  end if; 
   ctx_ddl.sync_index;   -- the error occurs here
   COMMIT;

END;
```

In order to successfully execute this procedure, I provided all necessary rights to the current user:

```
grant resource, connect, ctxapp to my_user;
/
grant execute on ctxsys.ctx_adm to my_user;
grant execute on ctxsys.ctx_cls to my_user;
grant execute on ctxsys.ctx_ddl to my_user;
grant execute on ctxsys.ctx_doc to my_user;
grant execute on ctxsys.ctx_output to my_user;
grant execute on ctxsys.ctx_query to my_user;
grant execute on ctxsys.ctx_report to my_user;
grant execute on ctxsys.ctx_thes to my_user;
grant execute on ctxsys.ctx_ulexer to my_user;
```

... but, unfortunately, when I execute the procedure I receive the following error:

> Error starting at line 1 in command:
>   EXECUTE put_file('text.txt', sysdate, 12, '.txt', sysdate, sysdate, sysdate);
>   Error report:
>
> ORA-20000: Oracle Text error: DRG-10017: you must be CTXSYS to do
>   this:    SYNC
>   ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.DRUE", line 160
>   ORA-06512: at
>   "CTXSYS.CTX_DDL", line 847
>   ORA-06512: at "my_user.PUT_FILE", line
>   24
>   ORA-06512: at line 1
>
> 20000. 00000 -  "%s"
>          *Cause:    The stored procedure 'raise_application_error' was called which causes this error to be generated.
>          *Action:   Correct the problem as described in the error message or contact the application administrator or DBA for more information.

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong, please?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem I show you're calling `ctx_ddl.sync_index`. You're not passing any parameters. This is allowed but [the documentation tells us](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/cddlpkg.htm#CCREF0652):

> "When idx_name is null, all CONTEXT, CTXRULE, and CTXXPATH indexes that have pending changes are synchronized. You must be connected as ctxsys to perform this operation. "

So the solution is you need to include the name of the index in your call.